# Select groups that have + and - z score values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm looking to group my data by the column `type` and select the all rows (of the grouped `type`) that have BOTH a positive and a negative z-score. In other words, I'm looking to select `type` groupings only if their z-score ranges above and below 0.

In the example data `test` I would expect the `type`s "Translation", "Signal Transduction", "Glycan Biosynthesis", and "Genetic Info Processing" to be separated out. I'm really struggling with where to start and below is my best starting point.

```
out <- test %>% group_by(type) %>% select(zscore < 0 & zscore >0)

> dput(test)
structure(list(zscore = c(0.775767217942226, 1.50431110062286, 
0.96844973768628, 1.13270780763826, -0.417688838401554, -1.16388703634018, 
-0.79027804814387, 0.497003183210411, -0.79027804814387, -1.16388703634018, 
1.37434643916904, -0.79027804814387, -0.79027804814387, -1.16388703634018, 
-0.572244270676755, -1.16388703634018, 0.291606810323695, 0.44589189244246, 
1.1176046488225, -1.16388703634018, 0.21485327846621, -0.417688838401554, 
-1.16388703634018, -0.117261781255063, -1.16388703634018, 1.22796644918627, 
-0.417688838401554, -1.16388703634018, -0.19999370182559, -1.16388703634018
), type = c("Nucleotide Metabolism", "Folding Sorting and Degradation", 
"Cell Motility", "Genetic Information Processing", "Carbohydrate Metabolism", 
"Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism", "Carbohydrate Metabolism", 
"Genetic Information Processing", "Metabolism", "Carbohydrate Metabolism", 
"Membrane Transport", "Transport and Catabolism", "Genetic Information Processing", 
"Amino Acid Metabolism", "Transport and Catabolism", "Translation", 
"Translation", "Lipid Metabolism", "Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism", 
"Amino Acid Metabolism", "Genetic Information Processing", "Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism", 
"Carbohydrate Metabolism", "Metabolism", "Xenobiotics Biodegradation and Metabolism", 
"Signal Transduction", "Genetic Information Processing", "Signal Transduction", 
"Carbohydrate Metabolism", "Metabolism")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 
54L, 57L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `filter()` rather than `select()` to select rows. And also use `any()` to look across all values in a group since any individual value cannot be both negative and positive. Try

```
test %>% 
  group_by(type) %>%
  filter(any(zscore < 0) & any(zscore >0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `var(sign(zscore))>0` as the filter condition

```
test %>%
    filter(var(sign(zscore)) > 0, .by = type)
```

which gives

```
       zscore                               type
1   1.1327078     Genetic Information Processing
2  -1.1638870 Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism
3   0.4970032     Genetic Information Processing
4  -0.7902780     Genetic Information Processing
5  -1.1638870                        Translation
6   0.2916068                        Translation
7   1.1176046 Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism
8   0.2148533     Genetic Information Processing
9  -0.4176888 Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism
10  1.2279664                Signal Transduction
11 -0.4176888     Genetic Information Processing
12 -1.1638870                Signal Transduction
```

## Logic behind

If you have either `+` or `-` only, you always have `var(sign(zscore))==0`. In another way around, if you have `var(sign(zscore))>0`, you can infer that `+` and `-` must co-exist

Answer (score 2):

`table`s of `sign`s per group should be of `length` integer 2.

```
> subset(test, ave(sign(zscore), type, FUN=\(x) length(table(x))) == 2L)
       zscore                               type
4   1.1327078     Genetic Information Processing
7  -1.1638870 Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism
15  0.4970032     Genetic Information Processing
27 -0.7902780     Genetic Information Processing
35 -1.1638870                        Translation
36  0.2916068                        Translation
38  1.1176046 Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism
41  0.2148533     Genetic Information Processing
44 -0.4176888 Glycan Biosynthesis and Metabolism
49  1.2279664                Signal Transduction
51 -0.4176888     Genetic Information Processing
52 -1.1638870                Signal Transduction
```

This preserves the row.names, hurrah!